# (Done) Question about resigning and being ignored should be reopened

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[I announced my resignation . . . and was completely ignored. What to do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189688/i-announced-my-resignation-and-was-completely-ignored-what-to-do/) should be reopened.

There's absolutely no valid reason for it getting Closed.

Comment: I voted to reopen. You should too.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I voted to re-open - the only reason to close would be someone thinking that the 'what should I do' depends on what the specific company regs are around employee exit.